# Access to my users details on Cognito is wide open to the web

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm still quite new to Cognito and used MobileHub's default setup.

Today I realized that anyone with the following information can request the details of any user in my pool 
 - My AWS account ID
 - My cognito user pool ID

As users' attributes often include email & phone numbers, that's not something I want people to be able to scrap.
The simple python code below does the job

```
import boto3
import requests
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth



region_name = 'us-east-1'
account_id = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
upoolid = 'us-east-1_xxxxxxxxx'


# Create a new identity
boto3.setup_default_session(region_name = region_name)
client = boto3.client('cognito-idp', region_name=region_name)


response = client.admin_get_user(
    UserPoolId=upoolid,
    Username='name of a user'
)
```

Question: did I misconfigure something? Or should I consider AWS account ID or cognito pool ID as confidential?

Comment: If you do not explicitly provide credentials, all AWS SDKs will attempt to find credentials from a number of places (environment variables, default credentials file, EC2 metadata service). Is there any chance that credentials are actually being supplied implicitly?

Comment: Well, I wouldn’t think so since I am running this code from a random python file on my desktop. This is not even running on lambda or anything that could be suspicious.

Comment: You can check if boto3 is loading credentials (code at https://pastebin.com/8DngwcpX).